# Is there any point to waving the flashlight around when exploring?

Tags: until-dawn

Most of the characters have a torch in their hand when you're controlling them. While walking, you can also point that torch in different directions. However, it's a little cumbersome to control, so I'd rather just get on with walking, but I don't want to risk missing out on seeing something important with it.

I'm a few chapters in now, but don't recall ever having shone my torch onto anything important yet. Should I give up waving the torch around and just concentrate on walking about, or is there some benefit to directing the flashlight beam in different directions?

I'm thinking it's possible it may illuminate some clues that I'd otherwise miss, but that's not happened to me yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the flashlight helps with finding clues that will alter the course of the rest of the story. From [this guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/until-dawn/tips/until-dawn-tips-survival):

> Search through every nook and cranny for these clues (**highlighted by light-up icons when you walk nearby or when you shine a flashlight in the right direction**), and look at the clue page to see if there were any you missed during a chapter.

I remember when playing through this game, missing even the simplest clue would cause great agony when I personally put the pieces together in my head, but missed clues that let the *characters* also put the pieces together and I got a less-than-stellar ending as a result.

Comment: Ah OK. I'd figured that the clues just show themselves up if you're in the same room as them, or have just wandered close to them, but I guess that walking towards them also causes the torchlight to shine on the clue too. I'll get back to waving the torch around as I walk about then!